# Time complexity of this function?

Tags: language-agnostic, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

```
algo(n)
   for i in 0 to n {
      for 0 to 8^i {
      }
   }
   for i to 8^d {
   }
```

Any kind of analysis or information about the time complexity of this algorithm will be usefull. Worst case, best case, lower/upper bounds, theta/omega/big-o, recurrence relation....etc.

Comment: What are your own thoughts? I'd be happy to help, but I think you'll learn more if you give this an honest attempt of your own first. Also, please add braces (`{`, `}`) to the above so we can see the scope of the `for` loops. As is, it seems as if the third `for` loop is **not** nested within the prior two, is this as intended?

Comment: What is `d` in `for i to 8^d`?

Comment: I have no idea how to write this properly but my attempt for time complexity is: (sum of (8^i) for i=0 to n) + 8^d. I will add the braces now.

Comment: @amit The depth to which a search algorithm reaches before finishing. It could be any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm runs in exponential time (`T ∈ Θ(c^n)`, `c>1`). You can analyse the number of iterations of the inner `for` loop (`... for 0 to 8^i`) using Sigma notation:

[image]

Since your algorithm is in `Θ(8^n)`, it is also in `O(8^n)` (upper asymptotic bound) and `Ω(8^n)` (lower asymptotic bound).

---

The above analysis is performed under the assumption that the `d` in the final `for` loop analysis is less or equal to `n`, in which case the nested two `for` loop prior to it will dominate (and hence we needn't analyze the last non-dominant `for` loop explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

algo(n) is basically made of two parts:

```
   for i in 0 to n
      for 0 to 8^i
```

and

```
   for i to 8^d
```

Let's start with the first. Assuming each iteration of the inner loop takes constant time, it's complexity is `C*8^i`.
Now, if we sum it across possible values of `i` we get:

```
8^0 + 8^1 + 8^2 + .... + 8^n-1
```

This is [sum of geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) with `a=1, r=8`, and its sum is:

```
1 * (1-8 ^(n-1)) / (1-8) = 1 * (-1/7 + 8^(n-1)/7)
```

For `n->infinity`, this can be approximated as `8^(n-1)/7`, and we can conclude the complexity is `Θ(8^(n-1)/7) = Θ(8^n)`

As for the 2nd part, it is pretty straight forward and is 8^d.

This gives total complexity of `T(n)` is in `Θ(8^d + 8^n)`